# I/O error on POST request for "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi

Tags: docusignapi

Getting I/O error on POST request for "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/***** when trying to create an envelope in DocuSign's demo endpoint. I was able to retrieve JWT token successfully but getting I/O error when trying to create an envelope from application running in Docker. Could someone please provide a solution  here?

Comment: Can you share your code? what is the exact URL (you can mask your accountID)? what is the exact error? where is it coming from?

Comment: This is the call to create envelope

Comment: @InbarGazit Code to create an envelope. 
"payload" param has required details for creating an envelop 

headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"); 
headers.add("correlationId", EnvelopeId);
headers.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + accessToken);
HttpEntity<EnvelopeDefinition> request = new HttpEntity<EnvelopeDefinition>(payload, headers);
EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = oAuth2RestTemplate.postForObject("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/1*****9/envelopes", request, EnvelopeSummary.class)

Comment: @InbarGazit

ERROR Observed

org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://demo.docusign.net:443/restapi/v2/accounts/1*****9/envelopes": Connection reset;

Comment: are you using the Java SDK?

Comment: Just wondering - why are you using the old v2 API and not the v2.1?

Comment: Can you try this code - https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/docusign/controller/eSignature/services/EmbeddedSigningService.java

Comment: @InbarGazit - I did try using v2.1 but still getting same issue. I'm using jdk1.8

Comment: @InbarGazit - This issue happens only when running in Docker. Result looks good when running locally.

Comment: @InbarGazit
What are the allowed addresses for https://demo.docusign.com and https://account-d.docusign.com. Is it only 64.207.216.101 and  64.207.216.102 or a list of IP addresses with range? we have to check if firewall resolves to any of these IPs.

Comment: @InbarGazit - Thank you, will check on it. Do you have any IP range for demo endpoint? Is it only 64.207.216.101 / 64.207.216.102?

Comment: https://www.docusign.com/trust/security/esignature

Comment: **NEW 209.112.104.1 through 209.112.107.254
​64.207.216.1 through 64.207.219.254
162.248.184.1 through 162.248.187.254

Comment: @InbarGazit - Thank you so much for your response. Meanwhile I tested the connection from application running in Docker, firewall attempts to connect 64.207.216.102 but the session ends with "tcp-rst-from-client" message. once after the JWT token is obtained the connection gets reset when trying to call "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/*****". That means should we remove restrictions for "demo.docusign.net:443/restapi/v2/accounts/1*****9/envelopes"  too? We had removed restriction only for "account-d.docusign.com". 

Your response is much appreciated!

Comment: yes, you need to allow both URLs, the former is auth only, the latter is used for API calls

Answer (score -1):

Suggest a great article about using Docker with DocuSign APIs - https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/using-docker-php-and-more (this one is PHP but the Docker aspect is the same).

Clearly, if this only doesn't work on Docker, this is a networking issue. The docker instance has to be able to make POST/PUT/GET/DEL requests to port 443 of DocuSign endpoints. I would try to open it up completely first (no restrictions) to confirm and then try to put the specific rules in the firewall to allow these calls.
If you can't get it working yourself - you may want to contact DocuSign Developer Support.

For up-tp-date list of IP addresses used by DocuSign go to https://www.docusign.com/trust/security/esignature

Comment: Thank you, will check on it. Do you have any IP range for demo endpoint? Is it only 64.207.216.101 / 64.207.216.102?

Comment: you can find all the IP ranges in https://www.docusign.com/trust/security/esignature

Comment: **NEW 209.112.104.1 through 209.112.107.254
​64.207.216.1 through 64.207.219.254
162.248.184.1 through 162.248.187.254

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Meanwhile I tested the connection from application running in Docker, firewall attempts to connect 64.207.216.102 but the session ends with "tcp-rst-from-client" message. once after the JWT token is obtained the connection gets reset when trying to call "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/*****". That means should we remove restrictions for "demo.docusign.net:443/restapi/v2/accounts/1*****9/envelopes"  too? We had removed restriction only for "account-d.docusign.com". 
Your response is much appreciated!

Comment: yes, you need to allow both URLs, the former is auth only, the latter is used for API calls